# C unsigned integer subtraction, macros, and typecasting

Tags: c, casting, macros

Apologies for the Objective-C nature of the example code, but I'm pretty sure the answer to my question is within the C standard libraries and/or the Apple `clang` compiler.

I have an `NSArray` with a variable number of items in it. I want to use the item count to create a value between 1 and 3. I'm using the C `MAX` macro, but it has some strange behavior:

```
NSLog( @"%d %d %d %d", 1, [tasks count], 3 - [tasks count], MAX( 1, 3 - [tasks count] ) );
```

the output of this log statement when incrementing the number of items in `tasks` is this:

```
1 0 3 3
1 1 2 2
1 2 1 1
1 3 0 1
1 4 -1 -1
```

I dug into the docs a little and found that the `count` function is returning a `NSUInteger`. The solution to my dilemma is just typecasting the return value as `NSInteger`:

```
NSLog( @"%d %d %d %d", 1, (NSInteger)[tasks count], 3 - (NSInteger)[tasks count], MAX( 1, 3 - (NSInteger)[tasks count] ) );

1 0 3 3
1 1 2 2
1 2 1 1
1 3 0 1
1 4 -1 1
```

(If you're unfamiliar with Objective-C, on a 32-bit architecture `NSInteger` is typedef'd to `int` and `NSUInteger` is `unsigned int`.)

I'm struggling to understand the typecasting that implicitly happened in my original code, leading to my unintuitive result. Can anybody illuminate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on your compiler warnings.  As you say, the Objective C bit is irrelevant, so I will refer to C from here on out.

Let's say your `MAX()` macro is defined this way (using GCC extensions):

```
#define MAX(x, y) ({ typeof (x) _x = (x); \
                     typeof (y) _y = (y); \
                     _x > _y ? _x : _y })
```

(The `MAX()` macro is nonstandard

When you compute `MAX(1, 3 - [tasks count])`, you get:

```
int x = 1;
unsigned y = 3 - [tasks count];
x > y ? x : y;
```

Now, it is possible to properly compare an `int` and an `unsigned` in C, but that's not the behavior you get when using `x > y` in C.  Instead, both operands are converted to `unsigned` (due to the "usual arithmetic conversions").

So your comparison is `(unsigned) 1 > (unsigned) -1`, which is false, because `(unsigned) -1` is the largest possible `unsigned`, which is `0xffffffff` on most systems (both 32 and 64 bit).

### Where is the error?

```
NSLog(@"%d", [tasks count]);
```

This is technically wrong, you are passing `unsigned` to `NSLog()` but using the `%d` format specifier which is for `int`.  Use `%u` instead, or cast your values to `int` first.

### Compiler warnings

The compiler will emit two warnings:

- It *may* tell you that you are comparing a signed against an unsigned when you compute `MAX(1, 3 - [tasks count])`.
- It will tell you that you are passing an `unsigned` to `NSLog()` when the format expects an `int`.

Comment: Xcode's default compiler config gives me neither of those warnings. If it had, I wouldn't have wasted two hours trying to debug this. I had to turn on "implicit signedness conversions", which then gives 150 other warnings I don't care about.

Comment: @jab: This also comes down to a matter of style.  If I were in charge of your code, I would leave the warnings on and fix the code until all the warnings disappeared.  My guess is that there is some unexpected behavior in some—or many—of those 150 locations in your code generating the warning.  The fact that these warnings are not turned on by default reflects, IMO, the reality that most code is sloppy and most programmers will ignore diagnostic messages if there are too many of them.  I usually compile with `-Werror`, which prevents code from compiling if there are *any* warnings.

Comment: This could easily devolve into a debate over strongly typed vs. dynamic languages... Suffice to say that most of the time, I'm not interested in the difference between unsigned and signed integers. Sometimes it bites me, clearly, but I'm ultimately wagering that I'd waste more time fixing compiler warnings than I'd save debugging these rare cases. Laziness can be a virtue.

Comment: @jab: Well, as long as you're okay with writing code with the kind of defects that these warnings detect.  I've been bitten plenty of times by signed/unsigned comparisons, and this type of error has resulted in a number of security vulnerabilities in various products over the years.  It's not much safer than a buffer overflow, and nothing I say will make you care about buffer overflows either, if you've already decided your position.

Comment: It's also not really about static versus dynamic typing.  Most dynamic languages make this kind of error impossible.  It's really more a quirk of how arithmetic works in C, specifically.  Some people call this the difference between "strong" and "weak" typing systems.

Answer (score 2):

3 - [tasks count] is done with unsigned types, so the subtraction wraps around, and becomes 0xffffffff. So you get MAX(1, 0xffffffff) with unsigned types.

However, you print this out as a signed integer, since your NSLog formatting string is "%d", it will make NSLog treat the bits of the arguments as it was a signed int, and the bit pattern 0xfffffff is -1.

Comment: Yeah. And of course, using the wrong format specifier invokes UB anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3: It invokes UB in this case, but using the wrong specifier does not always cause UB (you can interchange `%u` and `%d` for positive values in the range of `int`).